# How can I update an API Gateway service-linked role with a policy to access CloudSearch in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudsearch

I have an existing CloudSearch domain and an API Gateway. I'm following the steps for [Integrating Amazon CloudSearch with API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/api-gateway.html) to link the two.

Per the instructions, my CloudSearch domain has the following access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/aws-service-role/ops.apigateway.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAPIGateway"
      },
      "Action": "cloudsearch:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The IAM role is supposed to have the following permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
      "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
      "logs:GetLogEvents",
      "logs:FilterLogEvents"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
  }]
}
```

And this trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }]
}
```

But the `AWSServiceRoleForAPIGateway` role is automatically generated, and I'm not able to edit its permissions or trust relationships. It is missing all the necessary `logs:*` permissions and is trusted by `ops.apigateway.amazonaws.com` instead of `apigateway.amazonaws.com`.

My API Gateway resource is configured exactly as specified in the article linked earlier, but the call fails with the following error:

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway
does not have permission to assume the provided role
arn:aws:iam::********:role/aws-service-role/ops.apigateway.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAPIGateway
```

I've tried creating a new service-linked role for API Gateway, which uses the `AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs` policy. This role has the necessary permissions and trust relationship, but the call fails with the same error.

Is there something more I need to do to configure API Gateway to use the correct role(s)? Can I attach a new policy to an AWS-managed service-linked role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clear case of [rubberducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). While reviewing my question for accuracy, I noticed two things:

1. In the Method Execution configuration for my API Gateway resource, I had explicitly set the **Execution role** to the `AWSServiceRoleForAPIGateway` role.
2. In the CloudSearch domain, I also had allowed the `AWSServiceRoleForAPIGateway` role access.

I changed both references to the new API Gateway service-linked role I created--the one I assigned the `AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs` policy to--and everything is working as expected.

Thank you to anyone who spent time reading my question. I don't know how useful it is, but I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else who falls into the same trap.